# JSSOR html5 validation error on jssor-slider="true" attribute

Tags: html, validation, attributes, jssor

Friends, I am trying to validate Jssor slider as HTML5. But i am getting the following error: Attribute jssor-slider not allowed on element div at this point.
Description:

```html
<div id="slider1_container" jssor-slider="true" style="visibility: visible; width: 1360px; height: 0px;">
```

Anyone has idea about how to fix this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `jssor-slider="true"` is a dynamic attribute to identify and cooperate with nested sliders. No need to include this attribute in your code, please just remove it.

Comment: This attribute is not there in the HTML section. I think, It is dynamically adding from the JS code. So how can i delete this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As it is dynamic property, it is no harm, please don't care about it.